# filtering listview results after selecting spinner value

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I have 3 `spinners` in my project named standard, division and age. They contain values from json data. When I select a value from each individual `spinner` it shows all data of students in a `listview` respectivly (fetched from json).

I'm working with the following **JSON** data:

```
[
{
"name":"aarti",
"surname":"singh",
"age":"18",
"div":"A",
"standard":"7"
},
{
"name":"seema",
"surname":"desai",
"age":"17",
"div":"B",
"standard":"7"
},
{
"name":"tina",
"surname":"joshi",
"age":"18",
"div":"A",
"standard":"8"
},
{
"name":"megha",
"surname":"kale",
"age":"17",
"div":"A",
"standard":"7"
},
{
"name":"swati",
"surname":"marathe",
"age":"18",
"div":"A",
"standard":"8"
},
{
"name":"rekha",
"surname":"surve",
"age":"17",
"div":"A",
"standard":"7"
},
{
"name":"madhu",
"surname":"dalvi",
"age":"18",
"div":"B",
"standard":"6"
}
```

I am trying to do it like this way:
When I select standard 7 from the spinner it should display students information studying in 7th standard ("aarti", "seema", "megha", "rekha") and their other information too.
Then I am selecting value from division spinner say "A", it should take above result granted and accordingly display students from standard 7 and division "A". It should shows the result as ("aarti", "megha", "rekha") and their other informations too.
Finally when I am selecting value from age spinner say "17", it should take above result granted and accordingly display students from standard 7 and division "A" and age "17". Accordingly it shows "megha" and "rekha".

Can anyone please assist me

This is my MainActivity.java class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> AllStandards = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> AllDivision = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> AllAge = new ArrayList<>();
JSONArray jsonArray;
Spinner spinner_std, spinner_div, spinner_age;
private ArrayList<StudInfo> studentVOList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final List<String> item_Std = getStandard("data.json");
final List<String> items_div = getDivision("data.json");
final List<String> items_age = getAge("data.json");

/*spinner for standard*/
spinner_std = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerStandard);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_std = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,     R.layout.spinner_standard_layout, R.id.textViewStandard, item_Std);

adapter_std.getFilter().filter(txt);

spinner_std.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    try {

        String standard = AllStandards.get(i);

        if (studentVOList.size() > 0)
            studentVOList.clear();
        for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
            String stand = jsonObject.getString("standard");
            if (stand.equalsIgnoreCase(standard)) {
                StudInfo studentVO = new StudInfo();

                studentVO.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                studentVO.setSurname(jsonObject.getString("surname"));
                studentVO.setAge(jsonObject.getString("age"));
                studentVO.setDiv(jsonObject.getString("div"));
                studentVO.setStandard(jsonObject.getString("standard"));

                studentVO.setStandard(stand);
                studentVOList.add(studentVO);
            }
        }
        // Log.d("TAG", "List With All Students in selected standard: " + studentVOList.size());

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StudentsInfo.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putSerializable("list", studentVOList);
        intent.putExtra("bundle", b);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
}
});
spinner_std.setAdapter(adapter_std);

/*spinner for division*/
spinner_div = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerDiv);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_div = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  R.layout.spinner_division_layout, R.id.textViewDivision, items_div);
adapter_div.getFilter().filter(txt);

spinner_div.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    try {

        String division = AllDivision.get(i);

        if (studentVOList.size() > 0)
            studentVOList.clear();
        for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
            String div = jsonObject.getString("div");
            // Collections.sort(AllDivision);

            if (div.equalsIgnoreCase(division)) {
                StudInfo studentVO = new StudInfo();

                studentVO.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                studentVO.setSurname(jsonObject.getString("surname"));
                studentVO.setAge(jsonObject.getString("age"));
                studentVO.setStandard(jsonObject.getString("standard"));
                studentVO.setDiv(jsonObject.getString("div"));

                studentVO.setDiv(div);
                studentVOList.add(studentVO);
            }
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StudentsInfo.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putSerializable("list", studentVOList);
        intent.putExtra("bundle", b);

        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
}
});
spinner_div.setAdapter(adapter_div);

/*spinner for age*/
spinner_age = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinerAge);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_age = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  R.layout.spinner_age_layout, R.id.textViewAge, items_age);
adapter_age.getFilter().filter(txt);

spinner_age.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    try {

        String age = AllAge.get(i);

        if (studentVOList.size() > 0)
            studentVOList.clear();
        for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
            String age_list = jsonObject.getString("age");
            Collections.sort(AllAge);

            if (age_list.equalsIgnoreCase(age)) {
                StudInfo studentVO = new StudInfo();

                studentVO.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                studentVO.setSurname(jsonObject.getString("surname"));
                studentVO.setDiv(jsonObject.getString("div"));
                studentVO.setStandard(jsonObject.getString("standard"));
                studentVO.setAge(jsonObject.getString("age"));

                studentVO.setAge(age_list);
                studentVOList.add(studentVO);
            }
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  StudentsInfo.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putSerializable("list", studentVOList);
        intent.putExtra("bundle", b);

        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
}
});
spinner_age.setAdapter(adapter_age);

}//onCreate Method

private List<String> getStandard(String fileName) {
jsonArray = null;
try {
InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open(fileName);
int size = is.available();
byte[] data = new byte[size];
is.read(data);
is.close();
String json = new String(data, "UTF-8");

// AllStandards.clear();
try {
    jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String stand = jsonObject.getString("standard");

        if (!AllStandards.contains(stand)) {
            AllStandards.add(stand);
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException je) {
    je.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return AllStandards;
}

private List<String> getDivision(String fileName) {
jsonArray = null;
try {
InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open(fileName);
int size = is.available();
byte[] data = new byte[size];
is.read(data);
is.close();
String json = new String(data, "UTF-8");
try {
    jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String stand = jsonObject.getString("div");
        if (!AllDivision.contains(stand)) {
            AllDivision.add(stand);
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException je) {
    je.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return AllDivision;
}

private List<String> getAge(String fileName) {
jsonArray = null;
try {
InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open(fileName);
int size = is.available();
byte[] data = new byte[size];
is.read(data);
is.close();
String json = new String(data, "UTF-8");
try {
    jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String stand = jsonObject.getString("age");
        if (!AllAge.contains(stand)) {
            AllAge.add(stand);
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException je) {
    je.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return AllAge;
}
```

this is my ListAdapter.java class

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StudInfo> {
int vg;
ArrayList<StudInfo> list;
Context context;

public ListAdapter(Context context, int vg, int id, ArrayList<StudInfo> list) {
super(context, vg, id, list);
this.context = context;
this.vg = vg;
this.list = list;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)     context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View itemView = inflater.inflate(vg, parent, false);

TextView textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
TextView textViewSurname = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtSurname);
TextView textViewAge = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAge);
TextView textViewDiv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDiv);
TextView textViewStd = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtStandard);

textViewName.setText(list.get(position).getName());
textViewSurname.setText(list.get(position).getSurname());
textViewAge.setText(list.get(position).getAge());
textViewDiv.setText(list.get(position).getDiv());
textViewStd.setText(list.get(position).getStandard());

return itemView;
}
}
```

this is my StudentsInfo.java class

```
public class StudentsInfo extends Activity {

ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.studentsinfo_layout);

Bundle b = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle");

ArrayList<StudInfo> studentVOList = (ArrayList<StudInfo>) b.getSerializable("list");

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewShow);
ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_layout,    R.id.txtName, studentVOList);
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
}
```

this is my StudInfo.java class,

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class StudInfo implements Serializable
{
private String name;
private String surname;
private String age;
private String div;
private String standard;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getDiv() {
    return div;
}

public void setDiv(String div) {
    this.div = div;
}

public String getStandard() {
    return standard;
}

public void setStandard(String standard) {
    this.standard = standard;
}
}
```

i tried googling to find out solution but the questions i found all are based on searching listview items using edittext.i didn't found ant similar post matching with my question which solve my problem.can anyone please help me to solve this??

Answer (score 0):

**1. Override getFilter method in your adapter class**

**2. Use adapter.getFilter().filter(txt) in your spinner selection**

```
 package com.hughesnet.adapters;

 import com.hughesnet.R;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.Filter;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StudInfo> {
int                 vg;
ArrayList<StudInfo> list;
Context             context;
ItemFilter mFilter;
ArrayList<StudInfo> filteredData;

public ListAdapter (Context context, int vg, int id, ArrayList<StudInfo> list) {

    super (context, vg, id, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.vg = vg;
    this.list = list;
}

public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate (vg, parent, false);

    TextView textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById (R.id.txtName);
    TextView textViewSurname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById (R.id.txtSurname);
    TextView textViewAge = (TextView) itemView.findViewById (R.id.txtAge);
    TextView textViewDiv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById (R.id.txtDiv);
    TextView textViewStd = (TextView) itemView.findViewById (R.id.txtStandard);

    textViewName.setText (list.get (position).getName ());
    textViewSurname.setText (list.get (position).getSurname ());
    textViewAge.setText (list.get (position).getAge ());
    textViewDiv.setText (list.get (position).getDiv ());
    textViewStd.setText (list.get (position).getStandard ());

    return itemView;
}

ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter ();

public Filter getFilter () {

    return mFilter;
}

private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering (CharSequence constraint) {

        String filterString = constraint.toString ().toLowerCase ();

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults ();

        int count = list.size ();
        final ArrayList<StudInfo> nlist = new ArrayList<StudInfo> (count);

        String filterableString;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            StudInfo info = list.get (i);
            // Check for standard, division and age here
            if (info.getAge().contains(filterString) || info.getStandard().contains(filterString ) || info.getDiv().contains(filterString )) {
                nlist.add (filterableString);
            }
        }

        results.values = nlist;
        results.count = nlist.size ();

        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredData = (ArrayList<StudInfo>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137842/discussion-on-answer-by-pehlaj-filtering-listview-results-after-selecting-spinne).